# how to match /foo/:id/bar?any_query_string_I_want with regex

Tags: php, regex

This is a page URL and the :id param changes based on the resource and the query string can be all over the map.

How can I match /foo/:id/bar?anything

thanks in advance

Comment: `/.*/` meets your requirements. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to specify any restrictions on :id as you indicated it could change.
Taken at the most direct meaning of the question, the regex

`\/foo\/:id\/bar\?.*`

will match the exact string `/foo/:id/bar?` and then anything after.

Explanation:
String matching for the first part, escaping special characters (forward slashes and question mark) with a backslash. A period `.` indicates any character and an asterisk `*` indicates any amount of the previous character so `.*` means match any amount of any character.